# POSTGRESQL: Is it possible to count items in an array across rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My problem is that I have a table with data like this -

```
ID    COLORS
--------------------------------------------
1     ["red", "green"]
2     ["blue", "red"]
3     ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"]
```

What SQL witchcraft will I need to wield in order to create a result like that? -

```
COLOR    COUNT
--------------------------------------------
red      3
blue     2
green    2
yellow   1
```

Is it even possible with either a SP or View?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten the arrays by using `cross join` and then apply `count(*)`:

```
select v.value#>>'{}', count(*) cnt 
from tbl t 
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.colors) v
group by v.value#>>'{}' 
order by cnt desc
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G0OTiqPH).

Comment: You can remove the `#>>'{}'` part if you use `jsonb_array_elements_text()` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
create table color_test (id integer, colors text[]);

insert into color_test values (1, ARRAY['red', 'green']), (2, ARRAY['blue', 'red']), (3, ARRAY['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue']);

select color, count(color) from color_test, unnest(colors) as color group by color;

 color  | count 
--------+-------
 red    |     3
 blue   |     2
 green  |     2
 yellow |     1
```

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HpIj_y9Q)